# YOLOv4 video detection just loading

Tags: neural-network, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

Hello im trying to use video detection in YOLOv4 this is my command:

```
!./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg /content/custom-yolov4-detector_best.weights /content/test.mp4 -benchmark
```

But it just keep loading with a white square and it doesnt do anything after hours.

```
Loading weights from /content/custom-yolov4-detector_best.weights...
 seen 64, trained: 48 K-images (0 Kilo-batches_64) 
Done! Loaded 159 layers from weights-file 
video file: /content/test.mp4
Video stream: 2560 x 1080
```

Do you know what happen?